# add LED indicator and fan to power supply

Tags: power-supply

just a Grade 4 Filipino student asking for help.
I'm kinda new to this and I'm not good at math..

[image]

Corrections and add-ons:
1. input is 220V AC
2. transformer is multi output(3v,4.5v,6v,9v,12v)(but I used the 12v output only), and is 750mA
3. 1uF EC is 10v
4. DC fan is 12v and 0.14A

is my circuit safe and functional? which part of the circuit should I put my LED indicator and fan?

Comment: What is your question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ? Please revise the question with a specific question.

Comment: 1. am I doing this right?

Comment: 2. which part of the circuit should i add the led indicator and dc fan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1uF EC is 10v

A 10V electrolytic on the output of a 7812 regulator is asking for trouble. Try using a 16V or higher rated voltage.

140mA through the 7812 will get it a little warm because the DC input to the 7812 will be about 15.6 volts hence its power dissipated is 3.6 volts x 0.14 amps = 0.5 watts so make sure it doesn't overheat.

Comment: I've added a heat sink to the voltage regulator.. is that fine?

Comment: also, about the LED indicator and dc fan, any advice? thnx in advance

Comment: A small heatsink is probably advisable. As for the LED indicator, you don't appear to mention this in the question. The fan - you said it's 12V and 0.14 amps - I am completely unaware of the fan type and trust you have the right one chosen for the job (whatever job that is).

Comment: I mentioned the led in the title. Well anyway, where in the circuit should i put the fan and led indicator?

Comment: The fan goes across the output terminals and so does the LED BUT, the LED will need a current limiting resistor. Provide a data sheet link for the LED to work out the resistor value else if it's a common 20mA red LED use a 560 ohm resistor.

Comment: is this assuming that the 1uF ec is 16v or higher?

Comment: No, that is independent of the EC being 16V

Comment: btw, last question, why is a 10v ec at the ic's output a bad thing?

Comment: Ever tried putting a litre of water into a small cup - it runs out just like the electrolyte inside an electrolytic capacitor when the applied voltage is too high except sometimes it can be more dangerous! The output is 12V - you have to choose a capacitor than is rated to withstand a voltage higher than 12V just like the cup needs to be bigger than 1 litre.

Comment: hi again. We always get power outages in our city and we never know when it goes back on, so I wondered..
what type and value of fuse should i use and where in the circuit should i connect it?

Comment: A fuse is usually to protect the wiring to the power outlet and stop potential fires in walls due to cables overheating. There should be a fuse in your fuse box that does this so what do you want the fuse to do i.e. what should it protect?

Comment: the power supply, in case of power surges when the electricity back on..

Comment: A fuse won't protect against power surges. By the time a few blows the diodes in the bridge might be long dead. You protect these components by choosing ones that can take short term overloads. Fuses are to prevent collateral damage due long term overloads causing wall wires to burn.